# Can a Spheres of Power caster recharge staves?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, spheres-of-power

A [SoP caster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/) has no issues casting spells from [staves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves), but its unclear if they have the ability to recharge them. Would giving up a spell point each day be equivalent to the lose of a spell?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there aren't any rules that would allow you to use spell points to add charges to any magical item. You could potentially use [rituals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/rituals/) in order to recharge them. That would be somewhat funky on the bit that requires the spell caster to forgo a prepared spell or spell slot in order to recharge the stuff, so it would need DM approval. Though anything you do at this point is pretty much house-ruling it anyway.

Just giving up one spell point doesn't seem equivalent to losing one spell, especially not for high-level spells. Caster level should probably be a requirement as well (something like CL equal to staff's CL, or the level at which a Vancian caster would be able to cast the staff's highest level), and you should probably need more spell points for high-level spells. You could consider something like 1 SP for spells up to 3rd level, 2 SP for spells between 4th and 6th level, and 3 SP for spells between 7th and 9th level. This seems to fit reasonably well with the SP cost for using advanced talents (which mimic high-level spells).

Answer (score 1):

There's actually something in one of the spheres that explains how many spell points equate to a spell slot, it's 1 spell point for levels 1-2, 2 for levels 3-5, 3 for levels 6-8, and 4 for level 8. I'd agree that it would most likely need DM approval but those are the numbers that I found.

http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/blood

It's specifically under the Mana Bleed Talent that I found the numbers.
Creatures that possess spell slots instead lose spell slots, based on the level of the slot. Each slot is equivalent to a number of spell points: level 1-2: 1 spell point, 3-5: 2 spell points, 6-8: 3 spell points, 9: 4 spell points. The target creature chooses which spell slots are lost.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link to the page where you found those numbers. Sources are always appreciated.